# Плавное движение div при помощи клавиатуры

Tags: javascript, jquery

Код:

```js
$player = $('.player');

$object = $('.object');
$posObject = $object.position();

player = {

    UP: 87,
    LEFT: 68,
    DOWN: 83,
    RIGHT: 65,

    _duration: 1,

    _step:10,

    init: function () {
        $(window).keydown(function (e) {
            console.log(e.which);
            player.chPos(e.which);
        });
    },

    clash: function () {
        var posPlayerX = $player.position().left + $player.width();
        var posPlayerY = $player.position().top + $player.height();

        console.log('Pos player [ x: ' + posPlayerX + ', y: ' + posPlayerY + ']\n'
        + 'Pos object [ x: ' + $posObject.left + ', y: ' + $posObject.top + ']');

        if ((posPlayerX == $posObject.left) || (posPlayerY == $posObject.top)) {
            alert('Pos player [ x: ' + posPlayerX + ', y: ' + posPlayerY + ']\n'
            + 'Pos object [ x: ' + $posObject.left + ', y: ' + $posObject.top + ']');
        }
    },

    chPos: function (type) {

        this.clash();

        switch (type) {
            case this.UP:
                // up
                $player.animate({
                    top:$player.position().top - this._step + 'px'
                }, {
                    duration: this._duration
                });

                break;
            case this.LEFT:
                // left
                $player.animate({
                    left:$player.position().left + this._step + 'px'
                }, {
                    duration: this._duration
                });
                break;
            case this.DOWN:
                // down
                $player.animate({
                    top: $player.position().top + this._step + 'px'
                }, {
                    duration: this._duration
                });
                break;
            case this.RIGHT:
                // right
                $player.animate({
                    left: $player.position().left - this._step + 'px'
                }, {
                    duration: this._duration
                });
                break;
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    player.init();
});
```

```css
.player {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

    background-color: darkcyan;

    z-index: 2;
}

.object {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;

    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

    background-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<div class="player"></div>
<div class="object"></div>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что анимация делается для каждого пикселя, а нужно для всего действия, то есть, что бы все было плавно.

Если увеличить duration, то начнет подлагивать.

И как по-умному организовать столкновения?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала можно добавить немного CSS анимации на элемент:
http://jsfiddle.net/37rr4nLe/

```
-webkit-transition: all 60ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750); 
-moz-transition: all 60ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750); 
-o-transition: all 60ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750); 
transition: all 60ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750);
```